# Vlookup with condition

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need vlookup value from column C based on column A with criteria ..Column D should be blank (not used) and the result should not be repeated. it's a unique value in each row

[image]

Comment: Though i have this code but condition of column D (status) is not there

Comment: Please help in getting this resolve

Comment: Can you post the group of cells that you are using as the criteria ?